# file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I need to download a sample .csv file in my application.I'm using Code Igniter framework my function within controller in given below

```
public function dwnEmp(){
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $path = file_get_contents(base_url('/application/modules/payroll/views/employee/sample_Employee_details.csv'));
    force_download('sample_Employee_details.csv', $path);
}
```

whenever I'm trying to download the file it is giving me

> Message: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the
>   server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

I have made allow_url_fopen = 1 in my cpannel & whm through multiphpini but in php info its still showing allow_url_fopen=1.I have also restarted apache server but still the problem remains.

Comment: Maybe try curl https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php, most hosts don't restrict curl as much as they do `fopen` and `include`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the php.ini and enable the following 2 settings.

allow_url_fopen = 1

allow_url_include = 1

Restart Apache and they should be fixed.

Comment: value will be 1 or 0, instead of on/off

Answer (score 0):

Hi you also might need to update the mod rewrite from apaache. Please make sure that it is enabled.